# Join table with generated day series

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have this 2 tables:

```
SELECT sp.page_id, u.date_registered 
FROM users u 
  JOIN solved_pages sp ON u.username = sp.solver;
```

```
SELECT date_begin::date, (date_begin + '31 day'::interval)::date as date_end
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2020-01-01', timestamp '2021-01-01', interval '1 day') AS date_begin;
```

and I want to achieve a some kind of join. I want to count all page_id, with date_registered between the date_begin and date_end from each row.
Any tips for this? Thanks in advance :)

Table users

```
username | date_registered
------------------------------
user1    | 2020-04-01 20:00:00
user2    | 2020-04-07 21:00:00
user3    | 2020-12-01 14:00:00
```

Table solved_pages

```
solver   | page_id
------------------------------
user1    | page1
user1    | page2
user1    | page3
user2    | page1
user2    | page2
user3    | page1
```

The resulted table I want for only one single page (let's say page1):

```
date_begin  | date_end   | no_solvers
-------------------------------------
2020-01-01  | 2020-02-01 | 0
-------------------------------------
2020-02-01  | 2020-03-01 | 0
--------------------------------------
................
2020-04-01  | 2020-05-01 | 2   -> because user1 and user2 has registered in that period and both solved page1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  "I want to achieve some kind of join" is just not clear.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. I added some examples

Answer (score 1):

This looks like:

```
With Registrations as
(
SELECT sp.page_id, u.date_registered 
FROM users u 
  JOIN solved_pages sp ON u.username = sp.solver
and sp.page_id=‘page1’
), TimeSeries as
(
SELECT date_begin::date, (date_begin + '31 day'::interval)::date as date_end
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2020-01-01', timestamp '2021-01-01', interval '1 day') AS date_begin;
)
Select a.date_begin, a.date_end, b.sum(case when b.page_id is null then 0 else 1 end) as no_solvers
from TimeSeries a 
Left join Registrations b
on b.date_registered between a.date_begin and a.date_end
Group by a.date_begin, a.date_end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate test data:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE foo( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, d DATE NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO foo (d) SELECT 
  '2020-01-01'::DATE + '1 DAY'::INTERVAL*((365*random())::INTEGER) 
  FROM generate_series(1,100000);
COMMIT;
VACUUM ANALYZE foo;
```

Now, if all you want to do is count the number of rows in 31 day intervals, it is much faster and simpler to drop the JOIN and just use the fact that date-date returns days, divide by 31, and group by this:

```
 SELECT count(*), (d-'2020-01-01')/31 mon FROM foo GROUP BY mon ORDER BY mon;
 count | mon
-------+-----
  8334 |   0
  8535 |   1
  8497 |   2
  8390 |   3
  8529 |   4
  8525 |   5
  8316 |   6
  8486 |   7
  8504 |   8
  8581 |   9
  8553 |  10
  6750 |  11
```

...but that's not it, rather it looks like you want something like a rolling count. Let's try the join approach:

```
SELECT dates.*, count(*) FROM
(SELECT date_begin, date_begin+'31 day'::interval AS date_end FROM
(SELECT '2020-01-01'::DATE + '1 DAY'::INTERVAL * generate_series(0, 31) AS date_begin)d
) dates
JOIN foo ON (foo.d BETWEEN dates.date_begin AND dates.date_end)
GROUP BY date_begin, date_end;
```

This works but it is pretty slow unless there is an index on the date, and even then it's still pretty slow (about 350ms). Since the granularity of your counts is by day, it makes sense to simplify the data first by counting the number of rows in each day then running the join on that.

```
SELECT dates.*, sum(cnt) FROM
(SELECT date_begin, date_begin+'31 day'::interval AS date_end FROM
(SELECT '2020-01-01'::DATE + '1 DAY'::INTERVAL * generate_series(0, 31) AS date_begin)d
) dates
JOIN (SELECT d, count(*) cnt FROM foo     
         WHERE d < '2020-03-01'
         GROUP BY d) f
 ON (f.d BETWEEN dates.date_begin AND dates.date_end)
GROUP BY date_begin, date_end
ORDER BY date_begin;
```

This gives the same result in much less time (about 10ms). Note the WHERE in the subquery to restrict the number of rows counted to something that should at least include the period covered by the running count.

Using a window function is much tidier though:

```
 SELECT d, sum(cnt) OVER (ORDER BY d RANGE BETWEEN '0 DAYS' PRECEDING AND '31 DAYS' FOLLOWING) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT d, count(*) cnt FROM foo
     WHERE d < '2020-03-01'
     GROUP BY d) f
ORDER BY d;
```